# Change Mobile View to Desktop Version?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I would like to be able to view my sharepoint site on my ipad. I'm using Safari. When I go to my site page it's not the same. It's a simplified mobile version. I know you can switch browsers, like I did on my cell phone, to desktop version instead of mobile version. Is there any way to do this for SharePoint 2013 online, or is there only the dumbed down mobile view? It's bothering me because there's a large list I've created with multiple different views and collapsed groupings, but the mobile view isn't displaying it in the same intricate way the desktop internet explorer is. It's only displaying the first column I chose to group by. When you click on the column it shows the rest of the information in the edit mode. In conclusion, can you make the mobile view the same as the normal desktop view?

Comment: Nvm. Figured it out.

Comment: then post it as an answer so it can be accepted for the benefit of anyone else who comes across this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Goto your site settings -> site features -> deactivate the "Mobile Browser View" feature.

type out the site url in your ipad or phone browser again, it should show the desktop version directly. No need to click on "..."

Comment: Can I do this only for one single page?

Comment: No you cannot..

Answer (score 2):

If you click on sites at the top, you will then notice three dots in the bottom right corner. If you click on them you can change the view to PC.

Comment: "three dots". not dotted lines

Answer (score 0):

In Safari press and hold the refresh icon - it should pop up a panel at the bottom that says; "Request Desktop Site" - press on this choice.  This is a toggle - to toggle back to mobile view choose that same choice again.  In Google Chrome go under the ... (in vertical - not horizontal arrangement) and choose this same choice...
This is very handy in OWA as it allows you to choose "Open Another Mailbox" - which is not a choice in the mobile Outlook app or in OWA without switching to the Desktop view...